# SQL Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query in a marketing cloud automation studio activity

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [table 1]
WHERE
  [field 1] IN (
    'a2F6F000002WUVmUAO',
    'a2F6F000002WTqbUAG',
    'a2F6F000002WT8DUAW',
    'a2F6F000002WT9QUAW',
    'a2F6F000002WSghUAG',
    'a2F6F000002WTAKUA4',
  )
```

However I keep getting a Incorrect syntax near ')'.  error.

Does anyone know how to fix this error? I can't seem to find anything wrong with the syntax of my sql

Comment: Since you only have 1 "item" in your "IN" list, you may have to remove that extra comma.  (You only have one comma in the whole query, so it should be pretty easy to determine which one I'm referencing!)

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. I actually edited the original query, which had alot more values. I've edited the original post with a new query with additional values and its still showing a ')' error during syntax validation

Answer (score 6):

Remove the last `,` before the bracket.  It's the last item and doesnt need to be followed by a `,`